# Paste Excel range on active Word document opens Print driver host for applications

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I am implementing some code to embed an Excel worksheet on a Word document. Within the process `Print driver host for applications` is opening when paste (paste special) copied excel range on Word. I have created some sample code to recreate the issue.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string path = @"C:\Users\Aps\Desktop\excelDoc.xlsx";
     Word.Document doc = GetActiveDocument();
     Type ExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
     dynamic ExcelInst = Activator.CreateInstance(ExcelType);
     excelapp = ExcelInst;
     excelapp.Visible = false;

     workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(path, true);
     Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
     Excel.Range excelRange = sheet.Range["A1","E7"];
     sheet.Activate();
     excelRange.Copy();

     Word.Range wordRange = doc.Range();
     wordRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
     wordRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

     // insert embedded worksheet
     wordRange.PasteSpecial(
         Link: false,
         DataType: Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteOLEObject,
         Placement: Word.WdOLEPlacement.wdInLine,
         DisplayAsIcon: false
     );
     CloseWorkbook();
}

private void CloseWorkbook()
{
    try
    {
        if (workbook != null)
        {
            workbook.RefreshAll();
            workbook.Close(SaveChanges: true);
        }
        if (excelapp != null)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").OrderByDescending(p => p.StartTime).First();
            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Erorr handling
    }
}

private Word.Document GetActiveDocument()
{
    object word;
    Word.Document _activeDocument;

    try
    {
        word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        //If there is a running Word instance, it gets saved into the word variable
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //If there is no running instance, it creates a new one
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
        word = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

    Word.Application oWord = (Word.Application)word;
    _activeDocument = oWord.ActiveDocument;

    return _activeDocument;
}
```

In my application, I am using MyStyles.dotx file where we store our own stylings for word fields. 
Due to this Print driver host for applications app not closing issue, after using the excel embedding function, seems MyStyles.dotx file is not correctly closing and in the next machine start, a copy of MyStyles.dotx is opening. I tried manually closing the Print driver host for applications using Task manager, and then the issue with MyStyles.dotx re-opening at machine start is no longer there.

Why this Print driver host for applications app is opening at `wordRange.PasteSpecial`?

Is there a way to avoid opening the "Print driver host for applications" app when do `wordRange.PasteSpecial`?

If not, how should we close this "Print driver host for applications" after the excel embedding to the word is done?

Comment: FWIW I've never heard of a "Print driver host for applications app". It's certainly not part of Word - it must be some third-party thing (add-in?) You may need to ask the manufacturer of that tool.

Comment: @CindyMeister As found from web : "Print driver host for applications is related to printing operation. to communicate 64 OS printers with the 32 bit office."
Form the web results, it seems to have a connection with Excel.

Comment: On the machine where you are seeing this, can you change the default printer to be a different printer to see if the problem persists (in Windows 10 there’s an option to let Windows manage the default, and you would have to uncheck that). I just wonder whether the OLE server (Excel in this case) is using its printer driver to render the block of cells. Here, I didn’t see the problem with code that was similar to yours, but I suspect all my printer drivers are 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

its been 2 years.. but maybe someone need some answer on this

try to put

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the start of your function and later reenable it at the end of your function

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I also annoyed by this bug, and simply doing this stop the annoying freeze

cheers

Ferdinand

note: sorry yours was on microsoft word, mine was on excel, but i believe the problem is the same... so just change it to something similar, simply stop the automatic formula update.